# Custom styled select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

am trying to use javascript for custom styled select boxes from www.gerrendesign.com/entry_images/selectboxdemo.zip
and as I have plenty entries inside one of select box I need to make but am stuck in creation of scrolling function.

As this select boxes are compatible with almost all older and new browsers. I need only suggestion or solution how to add scroll in this linked/attached files above - if select box is populated with plenty of entries (example cities, states, or exchange rates...)

Am stuck here...
Thanks for your cooperation
Ivan

THIS IS CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // first locate all of the select tags on the page and hide them
  $("select.changeMe").css('display','none');
  //now, for each select box, run this function
  $("select.changeMe").each(function(){

var curSel = $(this);
// get the CSS width from the original select box
var gddWidth = $(curSel).css('width');
var gddWidthL = gddWidth.slice(0,-2);
var gddWidth2 = gddWidthL - 28;
var gddWidth3 = gddWidthL - 16;
// build the new div structure
var gddTop = '<div style="width:' + gddWidthL + 'px" class="selectME" tabindex="0"><div class="cornerstop"><div><div></div></div></div><div class="middle"><div><div><div>';
//get the default selected option
var whatSelected = $(curSel).children('option:selected').text();
//write the default
var gddFirst = '<div class="first"><span class="selectME gselected" style="width:'+ gddWidth2 +  'px;">'+ whatSelected +'</span><span id="arrowImg"></span><div class="clears"></div></div><ul class="selectME">';
// create a new array of div options from the original's options
var addItems = new Array();      
$(curSel).children('option').each( function() {           
    var text = $(this).text();  
    var selVal = $(this).attr('value'); 
    var before =  '<li style="width:' + gddWidthL + 'px;"><a href="#" rel="' + selVal + '" tabindex="0"  style="width:' + gddWidth3 + 'px;">';
    var after = '</a></li>';           
    addItems.push(before + text + after);
});
//hide the default from the list of options 
var removeFirst = addItems.shift();
// create the end of the div selectbox and close everything off
var gddBottom ='</ul></div></div></div></div><div class="cornersbottom"><div><div></div></div></div></div>'
//write everything after each selectbox
var GDD = gddTop + gddFirst + addItems.join('') + gddBottom;
$(curSel).after(GDD);
//this var selects the div select box directly after each of the origials
var nGDD = $(curSel).next('div.selectME');

$(nGDD).find('li:first').addClass("first");

$(nGDD).find('li:last').addClass('last');
//handle the on click functions - push results back to old text box
$(nGDD).click( function(e) {
     var myTarA = $(e.target).attr('rel');
     var myTarT = $(e.target).text();
     var myTar = $(e.target);
     //if closed, then open
     if( $(nGDD).find('li').css('display') == 'none')
        {
                //this next line closes any other selectboxes that might be open
                $('div.selectME').find('li').css('display','none');
                $(nGDD).find('li').css('display','block');

                //if user clicks off of the div select box, then shut the whole thing down
                $(document.window || 'body').click( function(f) {
                        var myTar2 = $(f.target);
                        if (myTar2 !== nGDD) {$(nGDD).find('li').css('display','none');}
                });
                        return false;
        }
        else
        {      
                if (myTarA == null){
                    $(nGDD).find('li').css('display','none');
                            return false;
                        }
                        else {
                            //set the value of the old select box
                            $(curSel).val(myTarA);
                            //set the text of the new one
                             $(nGDD).find('span.gselected').text(myTarT);
                             $(nGDD).find('li').css('display','none');
                             return false;
                        }
        }
//handle the tab index functions
 }).focus( function(e) {        


     $(nGDD).find('li:first').addClass('currentDD');
     $(nGDD).find('li:last').addClass('lastDD');
     function checkKey(e){
        //on keypress handle functions
        function moveDown() {
            var current = $(nGDD).find('.currentDD:first');
            var next = $(nGDD).find('.currentDD').next();
            if ($(current).is('.lastDD')){
            return false;
            } else {
                $(next).addClass('currentDD');
                $(current).removeClass('currentDD');
            }
        }
        function moveUp() {
            var current = $(nGDD).find('.currentDD:first');
            var prev = $(nGDD).find('.currentDD').prev();
            if ($(current).is('.first')){
            return false;
            } else {
                $(prev).addClass('currentDD');
                $(current).removeClass('currentDD');
            }
        }
        var curText = $(nGDD).find('.currentDD:first').text();
        var curVal = $(nGDD).find('.currentDD:first a').attr('rel');
       switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 40:
                $(curSel).val(curVal);
                $(nGDD).find('span.gselected').text(curText);
                moveDown();
                return false;
                break;
            case 38:
                $(curSel).val(curVal);
                $(nGDD).find('span.gselected').text(curText);
                moveUp();
                return false;
                break;
            case 13:
                $(nGDD).find('li').css('display','none');
                }     
    }
    $(document).keydown(checkKey);  
}).blur( function() {
        $(document).unbind('keydown');
});
  });
});
```

Comment: Please reformat your code. It's messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could render the list inside a div, that has either a fixed height or a max-height (depending on your cross-browser requirements). Presuming the default scroll bar is ok...

If structure is something in the direction of

```
<div class="select_data_container">
  <ul class="select_rows">
     <li>row1</li>
     <li>row2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS-example could be

```
.select_data_container {overflow-y: auto; height: 200px;}
.select_rows {display:block;}
```